# Construction of clarifying phrases

Tags: idiomatic-language, construction

I am wondering what is the most idiomatic way to add clarification after a sentence that might not be completely clear.
Does the second part of the following examples sound idiomatic or is there a more commonly used construction?

1. It's a bit complicated....my life (is).
2. They got here early....my brothers (did).

Comment: Those are all perfectly idiomatic, with or without is/did. They usually take a comma where you have an ellipsis. In a sentence like "They got here early, my brothers", where it may look as if the brothers are being _addressed_, adding 'did' clarifies things. In many parts of the UK "He's a bit strange is Derek" is colloquial. That construction would also work with your sentences. "They got here early, did my brothers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've written makes sense, and does look idiomatic.

Here are other examples which come to mind.

1. It's a bit complicated....my life, that is.
2. They got here early....my brothers, I mean.